# How to deploy Airflow to production being agnostic to Cloud providers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, containers, airflow

I am working on deploying an Airflow instance to production in Microsoft Azure, but one of the premises of the project is to develop an agnostic solution when it comes about the Cloud provider. My first idea was to deploy Airflow to production using Docker, so I could run the containers regardless the Cloud provider.

Is that a recommended way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow provides a [Helm chart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html) that allows you to install Airflow on a Kubernetes cluster. All cloud providers offer a Kubernetes service ([Azure AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/kubernetes-service), [AWS EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/), [GCP GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine)).

Here's the bare minimum Helm command to install the chart (from the docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html#installing-the-chart):

```bash
helm repo add apache-airflow https://airflow.apache.org
helm upgrade --install airflow apache-airflow/airflow --namespace airflow --create-namespace
```